# tmux, Solarized, and terminfo

Tags: vim, tmux, color-scheme, terminfo

This is a very specific issue but, based on what I've seen online, a surprisingly common one. I'm on a rather old version of Scientific Linux 5, which is based on Red Hat. I use vim with the Solarized vim color scheme, and my `TERM` environment variable is usually set to `xterm-256color`. This worked fine until I started using tmux. On non-empty lines in vim, the color scheme only extended to the end of the document's characters, the remaining whitespace being plain back background.

The stock fix for this in online guides is to set `TERM='screen-256color'`. However, upon doing this I would get the ominous warning: `WARNING: terminal is not fully functional  -  (press RETURN)`, when trying to do innocuous things like read man pages. However, everything seemed to be working fine, and the Solarized bug was fixed.

I've found a functional fix - using `TERM='xterm-256color'` by default and adding this line to my .bashrc:

`alias v='function _vim(){ TERM='screen-256color'; vim $1; TERM='xterm-256color'; };_vim'`

but it seems like a hack. Anecdotally, I've also set `alias tmux='tmux -2'`, which is a common suggestion with color-scheme-related issues.

I also know that the terminfo `screen-256color` is available on my machine.

So, really, the main befuddling thing is that, when using `TERM='screen-256color'`, I'm getting those warnings about full functionality when nothing seems to be wrong.

I don't have root access, so ideally any fix suggestions wouldn't need that.

**EDIT:** I should mention that `TERM='screen-256color-bce'` gave the same problems as `TERM='screen-256color'`.

Comment: `screen-256color` is the recommended `TERM` for tmux, did you try putting `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
` in `~/.tmux.conf`?

Comment: @romainl: I did, but the same issue was occurring. It seems that there's some issue with my system causing the "terminal not fully functional" warning to be raised when I'm running `screen-256color`, regardless of the context. This is despite the fact that my machine has `screen-256color` installed, and seems to be the root problem. Do you have any idea why this might be the case? Might it be possible to somehow install a new version of `screen-256color` in a local directory (I don't have root) and redirect the `terminfo` to it?

Answer (score 2):

The user's environment is not specified, but likely using bash and less (Scientific Linux 5 does not have `more`).

The package list on [Scientific Linux 5's ftp site](http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/5x/SRPMS/vendor/), shows ncurses-5.5-24.20060715.src.rpm, which does not include **`screen-256color`** (it was added to ncurses in [October 2006](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#t20061007)).  That system might have the later terminal database by some post-install change.

An application using **termcap** would not see this terminal description.  Scientific Linux's bash and less programs could have used termcap rather than terminfo.  A quick check of the changelog for bash-3.2-21.el5 says

```
* Fri Feb  1 2008 Miroslav Lichvar <mlichvar@redhat.com> - 3.2-21
- Link with libtermcap
```

On some systems, a missing termcap entry will cause a warning.  But with Scientific Linux 5, the given warning message comes from `less`, which checks its terminal description (using the *termcap* interface), to ensure that it can clear the remainder of the current line, the remainder of the screen and the entire screen.

In Scientific Linux 5, the `less` package is built with ncurses.  A problem with `less` using `TERM=screen-256color` would be one of these possibilities

- the screen-256color entry is not really installed, or
- there is some problem with the termcap interface provided by ncurses.

While there were ongoing performance-fixes for the `screen` program around this time, the former seems the more likely, as seen in this discussion of a poorly-written entry for `screen-256color` in early 2006: *[Re: screen-256color terminfo entry?](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/screen-users/2006-05/msg00064.html)*.  What I get from reading this is that there was some poorly-written terminal description (**not** part of ncurses) which produced the problem.  By the time it was proposed for inclusion in ncurses ([October 2006](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2006-10/msg00000.html)), the problem had been repaired.  In any case, it would have been corrected at that point.